# Pattern for Uniquely Identifying ForEach bound elements in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockoutjs viewmodel that contains a list of contact types for a person (phone number, email, physical address, etc...).

Each different contact type has a different [Template](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) that it binds to. (so a phone number field looks different from physical address field, for instance).

This works fine.

Now I need to be able to give each of the elements in a template a unique ID so I can reference them in markup and javascript. For instance, each contact type has a field in it called AddressType where the user can put in things like Home Address, Work Email, etc... It is the same field for each contact type. The html markup looks like this:

```
<label for='AddressType'>
    Type 
    <input type='text' id='AddressType' data-bind='value: AddressType' placeholder='Home, Work, etc...' />
</label>
```

Now this becomes confusing. When there is four different contact types on the screen, the Label tag winds up referencing the first element with an ID of "AddressType". When I have two phone number fields on the screen, the label for the PhoneNumber field acts the same way.

How can I give unique ID names to each templated form field in a Knockout Template?

If this isn't clear, leave a comment and I will create a JSFiddle which demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave off the `for` attribute of your label.  It is optional and if not supplied, the label will apply to the child `input` element.

Beyond that, see this question: [Unique ids in knockout.js templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233176/unique-ids-in-knockout-js-templates)

Comment: Ah, great question! Thanks for the link. My searching skills obviously were not up to the task of finding that question.