# KnockoutJS checked radio button when current row selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a list like below;

[image]

I would like to set radio button in user form when one of list row edit clicked.

My radio button's html like;

```
<form data-bind="submit: saveUser" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" data-bind="value: currentUser().name" />
        </div>
    </div>


    <!--Gender-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10" data-bind="foreach: genders">
            <input type="radio" name="genderGroup" data-bind="checked: $root.radioGender, value: id" style="margin: 5px"/><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!--Role-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: $root.roles, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id',value: currentUser().roleId, optionsCaption: 'Choose Component'"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Save User</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and radio button's click bind is like;

```
self.radioGender = function (gender) {
self.currentGender(gender);
if (gender !== self.selectedGender()) {
    self.selectedGender(gender);            
    self.currentUser().genderId(gender.id());
} 
    return true;
};
```

finally, it's the function when Edit button clicked;

```
self.modifyUser = function (user) {
    self.radioGender(self.currentGender());
    self.currentUser(user);
}
```

I read something about checked binding but I didn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use click bindings with radio buttons.

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  radioGender: ko.observable(0),
  genders: [
    {id: 0, name: 'undefined'},
    {id: 1, name: 'female'},
    {id: 2, name: 'male'}
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: genders">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: $root.radioGender, value: id"/><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </label>
</div>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Also: You don't need `name` attributes with knockout. But you should read about the [`uniqueId` and `uniqueFor` custom bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233176/unique-ids-in-knockout-js-templates) to get label elements to work.

---

Using the `value` binding with `$data` gives you this behavior:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  radioGender: ko.observable(0),
  genders: [
    {id: 0, name: 'undefined'},
    {id: 1, name: 'female'},
    {id: 2, name: 'male'}
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: genders">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: $root.radioGender, value: $data"/><span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  </label>
</div>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

I find this more useful than confining myself to a single property of the object in question, but it's not compatible to traditional (non-Ajax) form submits.

Comment: But my main object is CurrentUser that's why I use click binding because when the clicked the radio I assign gender value to my CurrentUser object. I updated my HTML form. can you check, please.

Comment: When I editing and updating I am using CurrentUser object.

Comment: You still don't need the click binding. Maybe you need `with: currentUser` on the outer `<form>`

Comment: You want to set the `currentUser` observable on `click` of the Edit button. This will redraw the form when it has the `with: currentUser` binding. And after that the `checked` and `value` bindings shown in my answer simply work.

Comment: It looks complicate for me. in my case genders loaded from api. thank you for your help.

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestion. now it's almost working but still can't checked radio button when I click edited. 

sample scene: I open the page the form is empty and when I click to edit. name and role is filled but gender radio still empty :/ @tomalak

Comment: Try to output the viewmodel to a `<pre>`like I show in my examples. It might help you find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to bind your radio button directly to the `genderId` observable in `currentUser`:

```
data-bind="checked: $parent.currentUser().genderId, value: id"
```